# JsonPath parse json error in java

Tags: java, json, regex, parsing, jsonpath

This is the JSON:

```
{
"datas": {
    "selling": {
        "3": [
            26452067,
            31625950
        ],
        "206": [
            32381852,
            32489262
        ],
        "208": [
            458
        ],
        "217": [
            27364892
        ],
        "226": [
            30474109
        ]
    }
},
"status": 0
}
```

My path is `$.datas.selling['3','206'].\*`
And I want to get both of '3' and '206' data. Like this JSON:

```
[
    26452067,
    31625950,
    32381852,
    32489262
]
```

But now it is not working. The error message is

> Multi properties can only be used as path leafs:
> $['datas']['selling']['3', '206']

My JsonPath maven version is 2.0.0 ([JsonPath's test website](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com)).

Actually the JsonPath can run in version 0.9.1, is it a bug?

How can I fix it?

2015-12-01
Now, the JsonPath new version solve the problem.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about jsonpath, but if it comes about json only then it is very easy to parse.

Comment: Why don't you just use the paths .datas.selling['3'].* and .datas.selling['206'].* and combine the results?

Comment: why you don't use gson or jackson..?

Comment: I think the problem is two fold: **1)** the expression you are using might seem logical but the underlying [source code](https://github.com/adjohnson916/JsonPath.java/blob/master/json-path/src/main/java/com/jayway/jsonpath/internal/token/PathToken.java) does not support it **2)** You unfortunately can't filter on *keys*. So either change the source code (which I don't recommend) or just use @NecroTheif 's solution by combining two queries.

Comment: @NecroTheif In some scene, I can't combine its.

Answer (score -3):

I use this way ,

```
$.datas.*.*[?(@>1000)]
```